# How to fix 'drawing line broken' in mapbox-gl-js

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I use mapbog-gl-js to draw line which source type is vector, but i found the line looks broken.I don't know which cause this issue the mapbox-gl-js or my wrong setting of the drawing style.Is there somebody can help me.

The issue looks like this:
[image: issue]

My detail code is:

```
var mapStyle = {
    "version": 8,
    "name": "Dark",
    "sources": {
        "mapbox": {
            "type": "vector",
            "tiles": ["https://d25uarhxywzl1j.cloudfront.net/v0.1/{z}/{x}/{y}.mvt"],
        },
    },
    "sprite": "mapbox://sprites/mapbox/dark-v10",
    "glyphs": "mapbox://fonts/mapbox/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf",
    "layers": [
        {
            "id": "background",
            "type": "background",
            "paint": {"background-color": "#111"}
        },
        {
            "id": "ext_lane_boundary",
            "source": "mapbox",
            "source-layer": 'mapillary-sequences',
            "type": "line",
            "layout": {
                "line-cap": "butt",
                "line-join": "miter",
            },
            paint: {
                'line-color': 'red',
                'line-width': {
                    base: 1.55,
                    stops: [[6, 4], [14, 7]],
                },
            },
        },
    ]
};

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    maxZoom: 14,
    minZoom: 6,
    zoom: 12,
    center: [-87.622088, 41.878781],
    style: mapStyle
});
```